# I want To track The Speed Of the fingure movement in pixel Per Second Is It Possible Any WaY?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, touch, uitouch

I want to track The speed Of the  Touch moved in pixel /Second
 Any Budy Having idea For This

Except the PanGesture Method

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean speed or velocity? i.e. If the user takes exactly 1 second to draw a circle, and finishes on exactly the same pixel they started on, would you expect the answer to be a) equal to the circumference of that circle / 1 second, or b) zero. Note that the implementation for b) will prove to be a lot simpler, but will work fine for straight lines.

Comment: NO Actually   I want is ==>If I Move My  fingure On to the screen  at that time i need the rate of change of pixel per second Which is provided in the PanGesture but Pangesture does not Supported by  ios Less than 3.2     please tell if YOu have Any idea???Thank You For Reply

Comment: @Dave : I Want it to move randomly in entire screen

Comment: Does your app use an NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval regular callback? Do you want AVERAGE speed over a period of time, or just the speed of each movement detected? I'm just trying to figure out how to best help answer your question.

Comment: i  need the speed of each movement  if u look at pan gesture library  there will be a function   - (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view; i want the out put like that as  this method return the  cgpoint  which is change in point per second

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll assume you want to know the velocity between **consecutive** movements, and not an average over a series of movements. The theory should be easy enough to adapt if you have other requirements, though.

You will need to know three things:

1. Where is the touch now?
2. Where was the touch previously?
3. How much time has passed since then?

Then just use Pythagoras to get your distance, and divide by time for speed.

When you get a **touchesMoved** event, it will provide the current and previous position for you. All you need to then add is a measure of time.

For that, you will want an **NSDate** property in your class to help calculate the time interval. You could initialise and release it in viewDidLoad / viewDidUnload, or somewhere similar. In my example, mine is called **lastTouchTime**, it is retained, and I initialised like this:

```
self.lastTouchTime = [NSDate date];
```

and I release it in the predictable way.

Your **touchesMoved** event should then look something like this:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       

    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint ptTouch;
    CGPoint ptPrevious;

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastTouchTime];
    [lastTouchTime release];
    lastTouchTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    [now release];

    touch = [touchesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    ptTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    ptPrevious = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat xMove = ptTouch.x - ptPrevious.x;
    CGFloat yMove = ptTouch.y - ptPrevious.y;
    CGFloat distance = sqrt ((xMove * xMove) + (yMove * yMove));

    NSLog (@"TimeInterval:%f", interval);
    NSLog (@"Move:%5.2f, %5.2f", xMove, yMove);
    NSLog (@"Distance:%5.2f", distance);
    NSLog (@"Speed:%5.2f", distance / interval);
}
```

Apologies if I've made a faux pas with any memory management, I'm still not very comfortable with ObjectiveC's way of doing things. I'm sure somebody can correct it if necessary!

Good luck, Freezing.